# Creating Preloader for SWF in AS3 Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, preloader

I'm a relatively new developer in AS3 using Flash Builder. My objective is to create a quick/fast loading small SWF preloader for a larger (30mg) SWF application. I can't include the larger SWF inside the preloader, but I can use external interface calls to get jquery to tell me what the speed of internet the users are using and figure out how long it should take to load based on the size of the larger SWF.

Right now, we have a large web application that takes around 5 mins to load if the client has a slow internet connection. So, we wanted to use a small SWF preloader that will display a loading circle or loading bar, and display options if the SWF takes longer than 5 mins to load. Kind of like error handling. For instance, for Safari, sometimes the player actually has to click the SWF in order for it to load. Is it possible to have a button on the SWF that will make it start loading?... Is it easier to create the preloader in jQuery? I'm just wondering if it's just going to create more issues using a SWF to load a SWF. Any ideas?...

Any ideas on how to tackle this beast? I've read almost every article about preloaders but there is nothing that references preloaders created in Flash Builder.

**I can't use Flash Professional or timeline. It has to be in Flash Builder.**

So I tried to use the below tutorial and I wasn't able to actually get anything to appear when I test it. I'm getting an error at the "run()" function:

Error: Error #2136: The SWF file http://local.myproj.com/MyProject.swf contains invalid data.
    at Preloader/run()[/Development/MyProject/src/Preloader.as:109]
    at Preloader/onEnterFrame()[/Development/MyProject/src/Preloader.as:46]

References: 
http://fortheloss.org/how-to-preloader-in-flash-builder-4-7/

Answer (score 0):

I worked until two years ago with a lot of these things and I know I have a few good scripts in my databases, but you are talking about Preloaded & activated loading were as in a preloader it is out of the hands of say a visitor what he or she can or cannot do, and in using a button (possible of course) the visitor has a choice to download or not! From memory there was never really a lot published yet over years of using Flex Builder I have collected some good AS3 scripts and modified them (including a progress-bar - but without time Indicator) to download in web Apps. or FLEX AIR etc. with AS3.
The small problem would only be to adapt any of it from mx to fx depending on what FLEX Builder you use!
I used my scripts mainly to download high resolution Images, Calendars, SWFs etc. with up to compressed 22 mB! Anyway, if Interested I have to look up my FLEX databases & Application to get it to you! rgs Aktell

Comment: Yeah - that's true. Would it be better to have just an html button, float above the SWF until clicked? I'm not sure if that would work, but use it as like a "start loading" kind of function?.. I'm not quiet sure how to resolve that yet.. Yeah, I'd appreciate any helpful scripts. :) Thank you!

Comment: Not quiet sure why you would think to use a Html Button are you not programming with Flash Builder and using MXML and / or AS3. Html is not needed for this as you do run a .SWF and here you can do anything & everything using Html ONLY as a wrapper page!!! I think that it would be best to write directly to me Att. Roland - WebFlashArtistry at gmail dot com to find out what you really need as only then I can look for specific & suited scripts! rgs aktell